# Certain squid functions don't work, sometimes nothing at all work

Tags: osx, proxy, squid

I set my proxy to `127.0.0.1:3128`, and then I added this to the configuration file:

```
acl blocked_sites url_regex -i "/usr/local/etc/squid/blocked_sites"
http_access deny blocked_sites
http_access allow all
```

Here is `/usr/local/etc/squid/blocked_sites`

```
facebook
```

This should deny all requests to urls containing "facebook".
However, I am able to access facebook from my browser. But often, I am not even able to access any website at all, let alone use such functions.

This is what it looks like in `/usr/local/var/logs/access.log` when I access facebook.com from my browser:

```
1450045715.071 1449 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 134759 CONNECT www.facebook.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/31.13.93.36
```

How do I fix this?

I have confirmed the squid process is running with pgrep and looking in the Activity Monitor.

I have also tried adding:

```
acl blockeddomain dstdomain "/usr/local/etc/squid/blocked_sites.acl"
http_access deny blockeddomain
```

To my squid.conf. Here is `blocked_sites.acl`

```
facebook
```

I have also tried adding .com to the url list, and stuff like `url_regex -i` to the conf file, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: What does the squid `access.log` file show you is happening when you browse?

Comment: @roaima lines like this `1450045715.071   1449 127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 134759 CONNECT www.facebook.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/31.13.93.36 -`

Comment: You did restart `squid` after adding `facebook` to your `blocked_sites` file?

Comment: @roaima Yes, I added that before I started squid the first time, and I restarted multiple times after.